# Is it possible to create a chrome extension showing an overlay div without adding it to the DOM?

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to create a simple chrome extension and at the moment I am injecting my scripts and stylesheets to the DOM to show an overlay div in the browser window. However when I change the tab or address the div won't appear until document is ready.

So is there a way to show an overlay div on all tabs without adding it to the DOM?

My manifest file:

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  "description": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": {
    "16":  "icons/icon16.png",
    "48":  "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "css": [
        "css/content.css",
      ],
      "js": [
        "libs/jquery-3.2.1.min.js",
        "js/content.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "My extension"
  },
  "permissions": [,
    "https://www.example.com/*", // I will update the div content from this URL
    "storage"
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "fonts/*.*"
  ]
}
```

I am adding it from my content.js like:

```
$('body').prepend(div);
```

Comment: @SureshAtta: Really? I find that hard to believe. Perhaps you could point to relevant information?

Comment: *"However when I change the tab or address the div won't appear until document is ready."* Your extension should be able to get something done earlier than that. You'll need to include a **lot** more information in your question. What does your extension registration config look like, for example...

Comment: @SureshAtta Could you please give an example then?